# How to transfer a C++ object to a web service using POCO library

Tags: c++, web-services, rest, opencv, poco-libraries

I have an image processing application that uses Qt and openCV.

for each frame, I should send the captured cv::Mat image object to the server to process it and get the results.

I should use the REST architecture for its low playload.

What is the tool that I should use to send cv::Mat to the server.

I am using POCO for portability.

I seek for the lightest solution to do that, I need a minimum speed of 10 frames processed by the server in a second.

I mean, is there a method to pass the C++ Object to the server without an explicit serialization?

Comment: 1) Serialize the image to a string (easily done with `imencode` and eventually base64 encoding), 2) send the string via REST 3) on server decode the image (base64 decoding and `imdecode`) 4) now you have your image server-side.

Comment: Thanks, why you did not put it as an answer? The problem is that I am still a beginner in POCO and searching to have a complete example in POCO sending a cv::Mat.

Comment: Because a complete answer will be too broad (as the question ;D). I was just giving you some pointers. You can easily find a lot of info for each step

Comment: Yes, your points are very informative.

Comment: @Miki for you're suggestion it's working but                                                                   
1) Frames per second will decreased to 5FPS. we will send data like object(ex :- {"photo": "Image data interms of bytes" }) and at receiver side it's easy to recover back                                                                                                                              2)If I send after imencode data as string it's like 20FPS.  but data like string.                                 3) I want to nearly 30 FPS how it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

With the POCO library, you can take a look in this answer: [HttpRequest PUT content in poco library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077126/httprequest-put-content-in-poco-library). He is sending a file on a `ifstream`.

In this answer you can check how to convert a `cv::Mat` into a `istream`: [OpenCV cv::Mat to std::ifstream for base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003981/opencv-cvmat-to-stdifstream-for-base64-encoding).

And finally, Thanks to polymorphism, the istream is implicity converted to a ifstream.

---

You can use the C++ Rest SDK. A code example of the PUT command.

[Source of code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj950081(v=vs.120).aspx)

[Library Github where you can find the full documentation.](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk)

```
#include <http_client.h>
#include <filestream.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;

// Upload a file to an HTTP server.
pplx::task<void> UploadFileToHttpServerAsync()
{
    using concurrency::streams::file_stream;
    using concurrency::streams::basic_istream;

    // To run this example, you must have a file named myfile.txt in the current folder. 
    // Alternatively, you can use the following code to create a stream from a text string. 
    // std::string s("abcdefg");
    // auto ss = concurrency::streams::stringstream::open_istream(s); 

    // Open stream to file. 
    return file_stream<unsigned char>::open_istream(L"myfile.txt").then([](pplx::task<basic_istream<unsigned char>> previousTask)
    {
        try
        {
            auto fileStream = previousTask.get();

            // Make HTTP request with the file stream as the body.
            http_client client(L"http://www.fourthcoffee.com");
            return client.request(methods::PUT, L"myfile", fileStream).then([fileStream](pplx::task<http_response> previousTask)
            {
                fileStream.close();

                std::wostringstream ss;
                try
                {
                    auto response = previousTask.get();
                    ss << L"Server returned returned status code " << response.status_code() << L"." << std::endl;
                }
                catch (const http_exception& e)
                {
                    ss << e.what() << std::endl;
                }
                std::wcout << ss.str();
            });
        }
        catch (const std::system_error& e)
        {
            std::wostringstream ss;
            ss << e.what() << std::endl;
            std::wcout << ss.str();

            // Return an empty task. 
            return pplx::task_from_result();
        }
    });

    /* Sample output:
    The request must be resent
    */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, +1.but I am using POCO for portability as I edited.

Comment: I edited my answer, looks that the linked answer have what you need. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but in the example he is sending a file. I search to send a cv::Mat or a pure C++ object in a general.

Comment: Do you really need to pass the value direct from memory? One option is to save the image to a file using the `cv::imwrite` command.

Comment: This a solution. but this will make the application heavier. I should process at a minimal speed of 10 frame/ second. I search to know how to serialize the object from the client part and to be able to read it form the sever part.

Comment: Check my answer again, I edited. Now you can check how to transform you Mat into a ifstream and then passe it to  the `copyStream` method from POCO.

Comment: Yes,  thanks a lot for your answer. But, I am searching for a solution that is less CPU consuming.

Comment: @ProEns08 you got the answer for this sending 10FPS using Poco